# Breakpoint will not currently be hit

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm debugging a function and trying to set a breakpoint on an API call, but I'm getting a "Breakpoint will not currently be hit" message for that line.  Here's the code:

```
bool __stdcall FileOperator::uploadDocument(char* filePath,long projectID)
    {
        char* filename="xyz.xlsx";
        char* docname="xyz.xlsx";
        long docID=0L;
        long lAttributeID=0;
        long lngAppID=aaApi_GetFExtensionApplication(L"xlsx");
        long lngWorkSpaceID=aaApi_GetWorkspaceProfileId(projectID,0);
        WCHAR strWorkingDir[_MAX_PATH];

        memset(strWorkingDir,'\0',_MAX_PATH);

        bool status=aaApi_CreateDocument(
            &docID,
            projectID,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            lngAppID,
            0,
            lngWorkSpaceID,
            convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(filePath),
        convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(filename),
        convertCharArrayToLPCWSTR(docname),
            NULL,
            NULL,
            FALSE,
            AADMSDOCCREF_DEFAULT,
            strWorkingDir,
            _MAX_PATH-1,
            &lAttributeID
            );
        return status;    
    }
```

If I try to set a breakpoint on the `aaApi_CreateDocument` call, I get this message:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  
No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated 
with this line.
Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations,
or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current 
debugger code type.
```

And then this line is skipped when the program runs.  How can I a) set the breakpoint and b) get that line to execute?

Comment: Try setting it to the end of the call, on the line with `);`.

Comment: Ok, that did it.  I thought the breakpoint was the same on any line, since it's all the same statement.

Comment: Debuggers can often only associate a single source line per statement, not a set of lines and so they usually pick the last line that the statement spans.